# return number of selected row in QTableView

Tags: qt, qtableview, qstandarditemmodel

I have the following code:

```
model = new QStandardItemModel();
channel = new QTableView(this);
channel->setModel(model);

model->setData(model->index(d,0,QModelIndex()), 0 );
model->setData(model->index(d,1,QModelIndex()),Channel);
model->setData(model->index(d,2,QModelIndex()),Unit);
model->setData(model->index(d,3,QModelIndex()),dimension);
model->setData(model->index(d,4,QModelIndex()),code);
model->setData(model->index(d,5,QModelIndex()),description);
```

I want you to just click on a box, return the row number where the selected field.

any idea how to do this?

Comment: Try looking at this, http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qitemselectionmodel.html

Comment: Are you talking about having it respond to a user click? Or being able to manually look at what is selected at any time?

Comment: is a user click. by clicking the user must return the row number therefore selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are referring to is called [SIGNALS and SLOTS](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/signalsandslots.html). QObjects emit various signals that you can connect to functions that perform actions. In your case you are probably interested in the [`clicked`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#clicked) signal of the `QTableView` (Actually provided by the super class QAbstractItemView)

```
connect(channel, SIGNAL(clicked(QModelIndex), 
           this, SLOT(handleTableClick()));
```

`handleTableClick` can really be named anything you want and would be a public SLOT you have defined to handle this signal:

```
public slots:
    void handleTableClick(const QModelIndex &);
```

When a user clicks on a valid cell, your slot will be called and you will be passed the QModelIndex. From there you can look up the row.

```
void Foo::handleTableClick(const QModelIndex &idx) {
    int row = idx.row();
}
```

Comment: I say this: "Object::connect: No such signal QTableView::clicked(const QModelIndex &index)"